# Prepare database data before running all unit tests

Tags: laravel, unit-testing, phpunit

I'm creating unit tests using PHPUnit in Laravel. Upon creating unit tests, I encounter that on some test I need to prepare database data such as selecting existing records, inserting new record and etc.

I separated each unit tests class based on my application functionality. So for example my application has user management module then I would have UserManagementTests class. Before starting to run the unit tests method inside this class I would like to prepare all database data needed so I won't need to query the database in each method for me to get the data needed for that specific unit test method.

I'm new to PHPUnit and I don't know what keyword should I search for this problem.

Other info:

- My application uses multiple databases
- Each database already have existing data and most of them should not be deleted during tests. So my option for some tests is to create new record, run the test, and delete the created record to preserve the original state of my database - I do this using the DatabaseTransactions trait of Laravel.

Comment: If you have factories for your models, you can use those either in the `setUp` method or test methods to prepare required data.

Comment: It is unfortunately not easy to prepare the data before each class. It is a lot easier to do it before each test using `setUp` and `tearDown` to remove the data (Or use trait `DatabaseTransactions` as you are doing)

Comment: @apokryfos yeah, that's what I realized.. so I just stick to using DatabaseTransactions and created method per class for preparing the data needed for the test in each test class. So at least I don't have to copy the same code for preparing data in each unit test method

Answer (score 1):

If you've got all the data you need in seeder classes, you can just call them as needed inside the test methods or the test class's `setUp()` method.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan;

Artisan::call('db:seed', ['--class' => 'MySeederClass', '--database' => 'testingDatabase']);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't use seeder classes.. What I need is to query on the current database state and use that data

Comment: I copy my live database on my dev database everyday that's where I get all my "existing" data

Comment: Then just create a database config option in `config/database.php` and use it as the `DB_CONNECTION` in `phpunit.xml`. However since your testing database changes everyday, your tests are not guaranteed to work every time.